# Webpack issue with socket.io-client import statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, html-framework-7

i am trying to use socket.io in framework7-react , when i am trying to import it. 
here is my import statement in react component.

`import io from socket.io-client`

it gives me error in web console, i am wondering what exactly making it wrong, please help me to figure it out :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
    at Module.eval (index.js:28)
    at eval (index.js:167)
    at Module../node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ms/index.js (app.js:5910)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:726)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at eval (debug.js:12)
    at Object../node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/debug/src/debug.js (app.js:5967)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:726)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at Module.eval (browser.js:11)
```

i am keep struggling to add it but no luck at all 
here is my `webpack.config.js` file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

const path = require('path');

function resolvePath(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir);
}

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const target = process.env.TARGET || 'web';



module.exports = {
  mode: env,
  entry: {
    app: './src/js/app.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: resolvePath('www'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '',
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    alias: {
      '@': resolvePath('src'),

    },


  },
  devtool: env === 'production' ? 'source-map' : 'eval',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    compress: true,
    contentBase: '/www/',
    disableHostCheck: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: 1000,
    },
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
    })],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(mjs|js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          resolvePath('src'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/framework7'),

          resolvePath('node_modules/framework7-react'),

          resolvePath('node_modules/template7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/dom7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/ssr-window'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/socket.io-client'),
        ]
      },



      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          (env === 'development' ? 'style-loader' : {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          }),
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl(us)?$/,
        use: [
          (env === 'development' ? 'style-loader' : {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          }),
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'stylus-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          (env === 'development' ? 'style-loader' : {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          }),
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc)ss$/,
        use: [
          (env === 'development' ? 'style-loader' : {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          }),
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'images/[name].[ext]',

        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac|m4a)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'media/[name].[ext]',

        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',

        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env),
      'process.env.TARGET': JSON.stringify(target),
    }),

    ...(env === 'production' ? [
      new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
        cssProcessorOptions: {
          safe: true,
          map: { inline: false },
        },
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    ] : [
        // Development only plugins
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
      ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: './index.html',
      template: './src/index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: env === 'production' ? {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true
      } : false,
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name].css',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: resolvePath('src/static'),
        to: resolvePath('www/static'),
      },
      {
        from: resolvePath('src/manifest.json'),
        to: resolvePath('www/manifest.json'),
      },
      {
        from: resolvePath('src/100.json'),
        to: resolvePath('www/100.json'),
      },
      {
        from: resolvePath('src/msg.json'),
        to: resolvePath('www/msg.json'),
      },
    ]),

    new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
      swSrc: resolvePath('src/service-worker.js'),
    }),
  ],
};
```

here is : babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-react',
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      modules: false,
    }],
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
  ],
};
```

Comment: What kind of .babelrc do you have at the moment?

Comment: @GuillaumeRichard , i just added the babel.config.js did not having any  .babelrc

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039
This mentions trying to remove transform-runtime  to fix it. it's apparently caused by mixing **import** and **module.exports**, and a plugin for babel might be doing that. I would focus my efforts on babel were I you. Sorry I don't know what else to suggest!

Comment: @GuillaumeRichard Thank you ! i will check it